# How can join table with IN() in ON couse?

Tags: sql

I have two table

User

```
id | name | category
1  | test | [2,4]
```

Category

```
id | name
1  | first
2  | second
3  | third
4  | fourth
```

now i need to join this both table and get data like:

```
name | category
test | second, fourth
```

i tried like:

```
select u.name as name, c.name as category 
from user 
 INNER JOIN category on(c.id in (u.category))
```

but it's not working.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Then you can fix your data model to use a junction/association table.

Comment: don't set it up this way. use a look up table instead. make a user to category junction table. look up many to many database relationship

Comment: "it's not working" is not a problem description. Why not? Quote in full any errors you get, or explain what the actual output was and why that differed from desired.

Comment: I guess there's a bit of confusion on how relational databases work, no to say a bad design choice

Comment: To get your final result you probably want to search for listagg as well.

Comment: What data type is `category`?

Comment: If that is Postgres, you can use something like this: https://rextester.com/TAPP23666

Answer (score 0):

As others have suggested, if you have any control whatsoever over the design of this database, don't store multiple values in `user.category`, but instead have a bridging table between the two which maps one or more category values to each user record.

However, if you are not in a position to be able to redesign the database, here's a way to get the result you're looking for. First, let's create some test data:

```
create table [user]
(
    id int,
    [name] varchar(50),
    category varchar(50) -- I'm assuming this is a string type
)

create table category
(
    id int,
    [name] varchar(50)
)

insert into [user] values 
(1,'test','[2,4]'),
(2,'another test','[1,2,4]'),
(3,'more test','[1,3,2,4]')

insert into category values 
(1,'first'),
(2,'second'),
(3,'third'),
(4,'fourth');
```

Then you can use a CTE with `split_string` to pull apart the individual category values, join them to their names, then recombine them into a single comma-separated value with `for xml`:

```
with r as
(
    select
        u.[name] as username,
        cat.id,
        cat.[name] as categoryname
    from [user] u
    outer apply
    (
        select value from string_split(substring(u.category,2,len(u.category)-2),',')
    ) c
    left join category cat on c.value = cat.id
)

select
    r.username,
    stuff(
        (select ',' + categoryname
         from r r2
         where r.username = r2.username
         order by r2.id
         for xml path ('')), 1, 1, '') as categories
from r
group by r.username
```

which gives the desired output:

```
/-----------------------------------------\
|  username   | categories                |
|-------------|---------------------------|
|another test | first,second,fourth       |
|more test    | first,second,third,fourth |
|test         | second,fourth             |
\-----------------------------------------/
```

I'm making a couple of assumptions here:

- You're using MS SQL Server
- The category values always begin with `[`, end with `]` and contain nothing but a comma-delimited string containing value category ids